# Prediction models used for Practical machine learning in R programming

Tags: r

Can anyone please provide me basic idea of what different types of Practical Machine Learning models we can use in R programming and few differences between each models. Everywhere i find material, all are complex. I just need the overall idea.

Comment: This might give a start http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Machine Learning is quite a large field, the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning#Decision_tree_learning) page already lists 13 different approaches. And for each approaches there are multiple (sometimes slightly) different algorithms.

I will give you a short explanation of Decision Trees and Support Vector Machines (SVMs), since I am most familiar with these two machine learning methods. Before we start, note that I am sometimes talking about a *classification* problem and sometimes about a *regression* problem. In a classification problem we try to identify whether a certain data point belongs to a certain class. In a regression problem the outcome is a real number.

**Decision Trees**

Decision tree learning is concerned with predicting the value of a target variable based on predictors by using a decision tree. A decision tree is a tree in which each leaf node (i.e. final node on the tree) contains the value of the target variable. All the internal nodes (i.e. non-leaf nodes) are labelled with one of the predictors. At each node, the path to the node one layer lower in the tree is determined based on the value of the predictor. This procedure is repeated from the top of the tree until the a leaf node is reached. Decision trees can be used for both classification and regression type of problems.

There are different type of algorithms for **single** decision trees. Two of the most commonly used algorithms are the CART (Classification And Regression Tree) of *Breiman et al. (1984)* and C4.5 of *Quinlan (1993)*. For single decision trees it is often desirable to prune the tree, i.e., remove parts of the tree that provide little extra explanatory power.

There are also extensions which create many trees, such as Random Forests (RF) (*Breiman (2001)*) and Gradient Boosting (GB) (*Friedman (2002)* for Stochastic Gradient Boosting). RF creates many trees based on different random subsamples of your data and then 'votes' for the best split. GB methods create many weak prediction models/trees to together form a stronger model.

Check out the following R packages `rpart`, `partykit`, `randomForest`, `gbm` and of course `caret`, there are probably way more, but these came to mind.

**Support Vector Machines**

SVMs (*Boser et al.(1992)* and *Cortes and Vapnik (1995)*) are learning models that analyses data used for classification. SVMs need a training data set where each data point belongs to one of the two groups. A SVM training algorithm creates a model which assigns new data points, based on the learnings from the training data set, to one of the two groups. To make the classifications, a SVM constructs a hyperplane (a subspace of one dimension less than the original space) or multiple hyperplanes in a high dimensional space. *Kernel functions* can be used if the data is not linearly separable.

An R package you can use: `kernlab` or `caret`

Other popular Machine Learning methods, but which I have never used are Neural Networks and Bayesian Networks. If I were you I should also take a look at these methods.

Lastly, the Bible of Machine learning (as my colleague calls it): [Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/local.ftp/Springer/OLD/ESLII_print4.pdf)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much @MarcelG . I appreciate your effort.